# Make a search box for a priceset on a donation page

Tags: price-sets

Right now we are using WordPress but planning to switch to Drupal in the next several months. So Drupal fixes are good answers.

We have a contribution page setup with a priceset that is quite large and only getting larger as we grow. In a year from now, that list will be well over 100 active pricefields with 100 disabled. I would like to add a search box at the top so that people can start typing the name and have it auto-fill options from the priceset.

My current best option is to break the list down by Class of ... But I would prefer to just have one "Pay Tuition" link.